# Creating parametric equations using points

Tags: cubic-spline, parametric-equations, function-interposition

I have points, `x, y`, and `t`, where `t=1,...,Length[x]`. I wished to make two parametric equation using the idea of `interpolation`, but not using the method in Mathematica. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Let use BSpline interpolation. There is working example:

#### Preparadion of data:

```
t = Range[10];
x = t*Sin[t];
y = t*Cos[t];
pts = Transpose[{t, x, y}]
```

#### Plotting result

```
Graphics3D[{BSplineCurve[pts], Green, Line[pts], Red, Point[pts]}]
```

[image: plot]